# Android studio: why do I get errors when I just run the simplest code

Tags: android

the errors imgetting are :

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Android sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>   Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
>   Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.

I'm sorry if these questions might seem stupid :).

every time I run the simplest code like just a text box with something is written in it I get these errors.
Also, when I run the default nexus 5 simulators it just loads up to the part where it says android but  nothing after that.

Thanks much appreciated.

Comment: check your sdk build version

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the target sdk to 23 and compile build version to 23.1.0 in your app gradle